# Implementation of a stable, in-place quick sort with a linkedlist

Tags: java, linked-list, quicksort

I am trying to implement quick sort, and for the usual non-stable version, I have the following code:

```
private static Integer partition(ArrayList<Integer> a , Integer p , Integer r )
{
    Integer x = a.get(p) ;
    Integer i = p ;
    Integer j = r ;
    while ( j > i )
    {
        while ( a.get(i) <= x && i < j )
            i++ ;
        while ( a.get(j) > x && i < j )
            j-- ;
        if ( i < j )
            Collections.swap(a,i,j) ;
    }
    return j ;
}
private static void quickSort ( ArrayList<Integer> a , Integer p , Integer r )
{
    if ( p < r )
    {
        Integer q = partition(a,p,r) ;
        quickSort(a,p,q-1) ;
        quickSort(a,q+1,r) ;
    }
}
```

but I need an stable version of this!

My instructor has told me that this (an in-place and stable quick sort) is possible using a linked list and using the first element of each list as a pivot. So I was looking for an algorithm that would lead me to this?! thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "non-stable version" ?

Comment: I think you're looking for [Partition Sort](http://www.math.grin.edu/~walker/courses/153.sp00/lab-sorting.html) - Richard Cole and David C. Kandathil.

Comment: stable means that when you are sorting an array like { 1,2,3,2,7,2 } , after the sort , the 2's that were repeated should appear in the order that they appeared in the original array .

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I dont know what that is , but I'm looking for what I said , an stable and in-place quick sort implemented with linked list

Comment: Yes. Look up the 2004 [paper](http://academic.research.microsoft.com/Publication/1771335/the-average-case-analysis-of-partition-sorts) by Cole and Kandathil and possibly the 2001 [paper](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0097539798342903) by Jing Chen.

Comment: mr @ElliottFrisch , in the abstract I just read there was no mention of partition sort being stable ! would you be so kind to make sure ?

Comment: It's a family of sorts.

Comment: I found [this link](http://h2database.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/h2/src/tools/org/h2/dev/sort/InPlaceStableQuicksort.java) in the Quicksort [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) page, hope it helps!